# MySQL match ( ) against ( ) - order by score?

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry I am such a novice at this.
Just cannot get my head around `match()` and `against()`.

I have a set of 10 variables, essentially answers from 10 questions.
I want to match them against an MYSQL table and then select 5 most relevant results in descending order.

I also want to display the percentage of the score for each of the result.

The variables are:

```
$a1 = y;
$a2 = n;
$a3 = n;
$a5 = y;
.
.
.
$a10 = n;
```

My table structure is something like this:

`PERSON_NAME, AGE, A1, A2, A3, A5... A10`

The results I want to be display is like this:

Peter Smith (100% match)

Jane Grey (65% match)

Jill Sanders (30% match)

Why does this not work?

Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT *, MATCH($a1,$a2,$a3, $a4,$a5,$a6,$a6,$a7,$a8,$a9,$a10) AGAINST('A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10') AS score FROM table_name WHERE MATCH($a1,$a2,$a3, $a4,$a5,$a6,$a6,$a7,$a8,$a9,$a10) AGAINST('A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10') ORDER BY SCORE DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
---------
$max_score = 0;
$data = array();

do {
    if ($row['score'] &gt; $max_score) { 
        $max_score = $row['score'];
    }
    echo $row['PERSON_NAME']." ".@number_format(($row['score']/$max_score)*100,0)."%&lt;br&gt;n";
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: "Will this query work?" Why don't you try it? :)

Comment: ^^^ beat me to it ^^^

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I should have rephrased it. No it didn't work :((

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag for example: 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. That will show you any errors. Most likely missing quotes, which are needed for strings.

Comment: `$a1 = y;` etc. that needs to be quoted since it's not an integer `$a1 = "y";` if that is what you're actually using and do the same for the others, since `y` would be treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php). If your variables are indeed quoted, edit your question accordingly to reflect that, it's deceiving.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing the search backwards. The syntax is

```
SELECT ... MATCH (field1, field2, ... , field N) AGAINST ('search string')
```

You're doing what appears to be the equivalent of

```
SELECT ... MATCH(y, n, y, y, ....) AGAINST ('field2 field2 ... fieldN')
```

Since you are HIGHLY unlikely to have fields named `y` and `n` in your table, you'll end up with a mysql syntax error due to the unknown/non-existent fields.

If you had even MINIMAL error handling in your script, such as

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

you'd have been told about the errors. **NEVER** assume success. Always assume failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.